# Nostrification of a diploma as a Ukrainian

Tags: degree

Good afternoon!

I have a rather difficult situation, I hope you can help.
My wife is a Ukrainian from Crimea, has two citizenships, at the time of the occupation of Crimea she was 16 years old (she just received a Ukrainian passport and Russia immediately came).
As a result, she already received a certificate of secondary education in Russia. She already received a diploma of higher education in St. Petersburg. As a result, as the war began, she left the Russian Federation and arrived in Ukraine.

Will she be able to get a Nostrification of a diploma as a Ukrainian in Europe? Because the diploma was actually issued for a Russian passport?

She has all the documents in her hands:

1. Ukrainian passports (internal/foreign)
2. Russian passports (internal/foreign)
3. Originals of the certificate/diploma.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly would this nostrification be for?  I think the answer could very well depend.  I can say that, for the US, there is *no* such thing as official governmental recognition of secondary school diplomas, and everyone who wants to know about your secondary education (for example universities considering admitting you) decides on its own what to accept (though note that secondary education is not a strict requirement for university admission in the US).  Most institutions in the US probably would not bother with trying to strictly verify her credentials.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I'm not an authority on this, but hopefully, my answer could be helpful.

If she has a degree in a sensitive subject, like medicine (or nuclear physics?) and she plans to pursue it, there might be some difficulties, eg a  required re-certification, at least initially. Even then some entry-level positions (eg in health care) might be possible.  Otherwise, I doubt this would be a big problem --- at least, I suppose not in the UK or France. There might be bureaucratic delays, but the main thing is that she's legally entitled to be in Europe, and hopefully people will be understanding. Also, several countries/universities in Europe probably have special academic programmes and other support. It might be worth contacting the local diaspora. Hopefully, something works out, and the best of luck!